# How to access a sharepoint list remotely using C# code (SharePoint 2016)

Tags: list

I would like to access remotely using C# code a SharePoint list in SharePoint 2016 to perform create, update, read, delete operations.

What is the best to way to do that ?

Thanks,

Regards,

Arioule

Answer (score 1):

you can take advantage of SharePoint `Client Object Model (CSOM)`. In CSOM, you can build remote solution, that can perform all the CRUD operations like you require.

In Visual Studio, create a solution and add SharePoint client DLLs references. To do basic operation you require two DLLs i.e. `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll` & `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll`. You can obtain these DLLs from SP Server kept at `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI` location OR you can use `NuGet` to add reference to these files.

This is the documentation by MS on CRUD operations. Follow the URL to learn more on CSOM and how to use it. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code